# Make typedef in a separate file to import

Tags: node.js, graphql

I'm working on a project in GraphQL, NodeJS and I'm trying to make a new file called `typedef.ts` which I want to import in my `schema.ts` but I'm for some reason unable to make it work.
The error I'm getting is the following:

```
Error: typeDefs must be a string, array or schema AST, got object
```

The following changes I tried so far in my schema.ts:

```
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import { TypeDefs } from './typedefs/typedefs';
import { resolvers } from '../graphql/resolvers';

const typeDefs: Array<string> = TypeDefs; // <- Added this

export const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    logger: { log: e => console.log(e) },
});
```

The typedef.ts:

```
import { types } from '../../graphql/types';
import { Types } from '../types/types';

const schemaDefinition = `
    schema {
        query         : Query
        mutation      : Mutation
    }
`;

    export const TypeDefs = {
        schemaDefinition,
        // Card Type Def
        cardDef: [Types.cardTypes.query, Types.cardTypes.mutation],

        // User Type Def
        userDef: [Types.userTypes.query, Types.userTypes.mutation],

        ...types,
    };
```

Please explain to me how to fix this as I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the minus on my question as was a legit guess as I'm learning those technologies. Would be nice to get an explanation if I get wrong with that so I could understand.

By the way, I fixed my issue doing as next:

schema.ts

```
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import TypeDefs from './typedefs/typedefs';
import { resolvers } from '../graphql/resolvers';

export const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: TypeDefs,
    resolvers,
    logger: { log: e => console.log(e) },
});
```

typedefs.ts

```
import { types } from '../../graphql/types';
import { Types } from '../types/types';

const schemaDefinition = `
    schema {
        query         : Query
        mutation      : Mutation
    }
`;

const TypeDefs = [
    schemaDefinition,
    // Card Type Def
    Types.cardTypes.query,
    Types.cardTypes.mutation,

    // User Type Def
    Types.userTypes.query,
    Types.userTypes.mutation,

    ...types,
];

export { TypeDefs as default };
```